# Facebook page shifts when FB is added to Chrome Extension manifest

Tags: facebook, google-chrome-extension, content-script, manifest.json

In the manifest.json of my Chrome Extension, I've added Facebook to the content script. For some reason, I'm not sure if this is a bug in my code or something to do with Facebook, when the extension runs with Facebook in the content script's matches, the entire Facebook page becomes shifted.

[Here's an image of the bug.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn9kP.png)I'm not sure what's happening nor what's causing this to happen. My other friends have experienced the same issue when I ask them to include Facebook into the manifest.

The relevant code looks like this:

```
"content_scripts": [{
"matches": [
  "http://*.facebook.com/*",
  "https://*.facebook.com/*",
  "https://*.twitter.com/**",
  "https://*.reddit.com/**"
],
"css": ["bootstrap.min.css","content.css","twitter.css"],
"js": ["reddit.js", "content.js","twitter.js"],
"run_at": "document_end"
```

}],

My extension works great on Reddit and Twitter. I've isolated the Facebook issue to here. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: It means you inject the wrong CSS but you didn't show it to us so we can't help.

Comment: I've updated it to include the entire content scripts.

Comment: You're adding a lot of CSS into the matching pages, including bootstrap which may interfere with CSS used by the site itself, so it's only natural some sites break.

Comment: The bootstrap injection seems to be the issue. Thank you!